# Django calculation with many TimeFields

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a webapp, which should calculate with several `TimeField` objects.
No I stuck at one point. How is it possible to add different `TimeFields` together and subtract a `DecimalField` from the outcome `TimeField`.
I've tried different ways. For example to convert the `TimeFields` into a `str-object` (which doesn't work either...). Does anyone of you got an idea how I can handle that issue? A small hint would be a pleasure for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you *actually* trying to do? :) I'll have to guess to begin with...

Remember `TimeField`s carry `datetime.time` objects, which are "clock time", i.e. from midnight to midnight.
I'm assuming you want to convert them to a form that you can handle arithmetically -- seconds since midnight works fine for that.

I'm using raw `datetime.time` objects here for simplicity, but it's the same thing with Django's TimeFields.

```
import datetime, decimal

def to_seconds_after_midnight(t):
    return t.hour * 60 * 60 + t.minute * 60 + t.second + (t.microsecond / 1000000.)

hourly_fee = decimal.Decimal(90)  # for example.

time_1 = datetime.time(13, 15)
time_2 = datetime.time(16, 20)

second_interval = decimal.Decimal(
    to_seconds_after_midnight(time_2) -
    to_seconds_after_midnight(time_1)
)
print(hourly_fee * (second_interval / 60 / 60))  # The output is 277.5.
```

HTH :)